# How to grab data through a link table and pivot rows to columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get some data from one of my tables through a link table, and to output multiple rows as a column/s - this is a personal project designed to help me learn as I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm not really even sure what to search for - I've looked up what I could but with no success.

What I have is

***Table 1 - Plays***

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | gamename1 |
| 2 | gamename1 |
| 3 | gamename2 |

***Table 2 - Players***

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | playername1 |
| 2 | playername1 |
| 3 | playername2 |

***Linktable***

| play_id | players_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

***What I'd like to see*** (doesn't have to match this exactly, but something that shows all players per play_id with one play_id per row)

| Game id | Player name1 | Player name2 | Player name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gamename1 | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| gamename1 | name2 |  |  |
| gamename2 | name2 | name3 |  |

I assumed this would work but it hasn't, I'm able to get either just the first player per game (using the group by), or if I remove it I get a line for every entry in my link table.

```sql
SELECT
    plays.name,
    players.name
FROM
    plays
    INNER JOIN linktable
        ON linktable.play_id = play.id
    INNER JOIN players
        ON linktable.players_id = players.id
GROUP BY
    plays.id
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Sorry eshirvana - I don't use stackoverflow much and was writing from my phone, but I've done what you asked now :)

Comment: you need to use [pivot](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pivoting-in-mariadb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider starting with `Linktable` and then `LEFT JOIN` (`INNER JOIN` if there are no orphaned links) to the lookup tables, `Plays` and `Players`. Then run conditional aggregation for pivoting:

```sql
SELECT p.`name` AS gamername
     , CASE WHEN ps.id = 1 THEN ps.name END AS Player_name_1
     , CASE WHEN ps.id = 2 THEN ps.name END AS Player_name_2
     , CASE WHEN ps.id = 3 THEN ps.name END AS Player_name_3

FROM linktable l
LEFT JOIN plays p
   ON l.play_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN players ps
   ON l.player_id = ps.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/WQFXK60030)</kbd>

| gamername | Player_name_1 | Player_name_2 | Player_name_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gamename1 | playername1 | NULL | NULL |
| gamename1 | NULL | playername2 | NULL |
| gamename2 | NULL | NULL | playername3 |
| gamename3 | NULL | playername2 | NULL |
| gamename3 | NUL | playername2 | NULL |
| gamename3 | NULL | NULL | playername3 |

Even better if you aggregate:

```sql
SELECT p.`name` AS gamername
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ps.id = 1 THEN ps.name END) AS Player_name_1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ps.id = 2 THEN ps.name END) AS Player_name_2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ps.id = 3 THEN ps.name END) AS Player_name_3

FROM linktable l
LEFT JOIN plays p
   ON l.play_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN players ps
   ON l.player_id = ps.id
GROUP BY p.`name`;
```

| gamername | Player_name_1 | Player_name_2 | Player_name_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gamename1 | playername1 | playername2 | playername3 |
| gamename2 | NULL | playername2 | NULL |
| gamename3 | NULL | playername2 | playername3 |

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!